# Tikz lines from node to node: E.g. Tikz for curves in coordinate systems

Tags: coordinates, nodes, system, curve, tikz

Tikz capabilities to draw lines from node to node a very useful, e.g, for something like:

[image: Example how Tikz works nicely]

However, if the node should have size 0 (i.e., no description) the outgoing or incoming line stops before the actual point. This is for instance the case if it is only used to mark a point in the coordinate system,  See, e.g., node (1,1) or (0,0) in the following picture:

[image: Tikz lines in coordinate system that stop too early]

The code for the second picture writes:

```
\node at(0,0) (origin) {};
\node[below = 0.0cm of origin]{$(0,0)$};
\node[above = 3cm of origin] (y) {$y$};
\node[right = 3cm of origin] (z) {$z$};
\node[above = 2cm of origin, left] (y1) {$1$};
\node[right = 2cm of origin, below] (z1) {$1$};
\node[right = 2cm of y1] (yz1) {};
\node[above = 2.5cm of z] (endgz) {};
\node[above = 3cm of z] (yz) {};
\node[above = 1cm of origin] (p0) {};
\draw[fill](p0) circle(0.06cm);
\node[left=0cm of p0]{$g(0)=p0$};
\draw[fill](yz1) circle(0.06cm);
\draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (y);
\draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (z);

\draw (origin) -- node [above = 1cm] {$y(z)=z$} (yz);
\draw (p0) .. controls +(0:1cm) and +(205:1cm) .. (endgz) node [below] {$g(z)$} ;

\draw (y1) -- (yz1);
\draw (z1) -- (yz1);
```

How can this be "corrected" without giving absolute coordinates instead of relative ones to nodes? I find it very attractive to not always give absolute coordinates as this makes the image much more adaptable for future and generalized use.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `inner sep`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] at(0,0) (origin) {};
\node[below = 0.0cm of origin]{$(0,0)$};
\node[above = 3cm of origin] (y) {$y$};
\node[right = 3cm of origin] (z) {$z$};
\node[above = 2cm of origin, left] (y1) {$1$};
\node[right = 2cm of origin, below] (z1) {$1$};
\node[inner sep=0pt,right = 2cm of y1] (yz1) {};
\node[above = 2.5cm of z] (endgz) {};
\node[above = 3cm of z] (yz) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt,above = 1cm of origin] (p0) {};
\draw[fill](p0) circle(0.06cm);
\node[left=0cm of p0]{$g(0)=p0$};
\draw[fill](yz1) circle(0.06cm);
\draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (y);
\draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (z);

\draw (origin) -- node [above = 1cm] {$y(z)=z$} (yz);
\draw (p0) .. controls +(0:1cm) and +(205:1cm) .. (endgz) node [below] {$g(z)$} ;

\draw (y1) -- (yz1);
\draw (z1) -- (yz1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```